# executing ajax success function- jQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've searched around for this error and none of the solutions appear to help me with what I am getting.  I am doing an ajax request, and I am trying to retrieve the json output released by the server. I can print out the json that i am trying to capture (via console.log()) not process it in the jQuery.parsejson(). I keep getting a "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o" error. Please can someone advise?

my code:

```
  // Make ajax request 
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/multipleFileUpload_adam/webservice/delete_pdf.php',
            data: {delete_array: jsonString},
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data){
              console.log(data);
                var x = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                    },
```

console.log(data) gives the following ( am trying to retrieve the  'success_deleted' array:

```
 Object {success_delete: Array[2], unsuccess_delete: Array[0], input array: Object}
```

if I remove the line of code :

```
  var x = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
```

Then I am able to get the console.log(data) to work. if i add it i get the error mentioned above.

Comment: I may be completely missing the question, but can't you just assign `x` to `data.success_delete`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
dataType: 'json',
```

tells jQuery to ignore the content-type returned by the server and always parse the response as if it was JSON.

Then:

```
success: function(data){
```

The JavaScript value (which is an object) that you get from parsing the JSON is passed into `data`.

This line:

```
jQuery.parseJSON(data);
```

1. Takes the value of `data` (an object)
2. Converts it into a string (which will be `"[object Object]"`)
3. Tries to parse that string as JSON (which it isn't).

> Then I am able to get the console.log(data) to work. if i add it i get the error mentioned above.

Yes. That is the expected behaviour. Don't do that. Just work with the already parsed data in `data`.

Comment: so  by adding the line 'dataType: "json"', the json response that i get from the server is automatically parsed to a Javascript object which is then placed in 'data'?

Comment: If the server responds with the correct content type then specifying `dataType` makes no difference. If jQuery thinks it is getting JSON then a JSON response will be parsed (into an object, array, string, number, boolean or null) and the result will be passed as the argument to success.

Answer (score 2):

there is a parse error because data is already an object so it is expecting json and getting Object. 'O' is the unexpected character. Try without the parseJSON function.